# how to get comments from html or jsp page using jericho html parser

Tags: jericho-html-parser

How to get comments like `//Comments` & `/*Comments*/` from a html and jsp page.

I have got comments `<!--Comments-->`,`<%--Comments--%>`,`<%Comments%>` in following way using jericho html parser.

```
List<Tag> comments = source.getAllTags(StartTagType.COMMENT);(<!--Comments-->)
List<Tag> serverSideComments = source.getAllTags(StartTagType.SERVER_COMMON_COMMENT);
(<%--Comments--%>)
List<Tag> serverComments = source.getAllTags(StartTagType.SERVER_COMMON);("<%Comments%>")
```

but I am not able to find for `//` & `/*Comments*/`.

Answer (score 0):

Comments in html must start with <. If you add something stating with // will be interpreted just like a text.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_comments.asp
I think this is a standard and jericho does not have a way of customizing tags.